# Xcode ERROR: 400: error -66680

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

is for a live stream radio using a .pls file

this one is under the **ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)play:(id)sender {

    NSString *stream = @"http://yp.shoutcast.com/sbin/tunein-station.pls?id=656420";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stream];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [_music loadRequest:request];
}
@end
```

this one is under the **ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *music;
- (IBAction)play:(id)sender;


@end
```

> Nov 30 01:04:13 Jairons-Mac-mini.local G106.3[12074]: 01:04:13.091
>   ERROR:     98: Error '!obj' trying to fetch default input device's
>   sample rate Nov 30 01:04:13 Jairons-Mac-mini.local G106.3[12074]:
>   01:04:13.091 ERROR:     100: Error getting audio input device sample
>   rate: '!obj' Nov 30 01:04:13 Jairons-Mac-mini.local G106.3[12074]:
>   01:04:13.091 WARNING:   230: The input device is 0x0; '(null)' Nov 30
>   01:04:13 Jairons-Mac-mini.local G106.3[12074]: 01:04:13.091 WARNING:
>   234: The output device is 0x2a; 'AppleHDAEngineOutput:1B,0,1,2:0' Nov
>   30 01:04:13 Jairons-Mac-mini.local G106.3[12074]: 01:04:13.092 ERROR: 
>   400: error '!obj' Nov 30 01:04:13 Jairons-Mac-mini.local
>   G106.3[12074]: 01:04:13.092 ERROR:     400: error -66680 Nov 30
>   01:04:13 Jairons-Mac-mini.local G106.3[12074]: 01:04:13.092 ERROR:
>   113: * * * NULL AQIONode object
>        Nov 30 01:04:13 Jairons-Mac-mini.local G106.3[12074]: 01:04:13.092 ERROR:     400: error -66680 Nov 30 01:04:13
>   Jairons-Mac-mini.local G106.3[12074]: 01:04:13.093 ERROR:     400:
>   error -66680 Nov 30 01:04:13 Jairons-Mac-mini.local G106.3[12074]:
>   01:04:13.093 ERROR:     703: Can't make UISound Renderer Nov 30
>   01:04:13 Jairons-Mac-mini.local G106.3[12074]: 01:04:13.093 ERROR:
>   400: error -66680 Nov 30 01:04:14 Jairons-Mac-mini.local
>   G106.3[12074]: 01:04:14.007 ERROR:     400: error -66680

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.  It is a bit difficult to tell what is going on from that list of errors.  Could you try to describe exactly what you were trying to do and can you post the relevant code?

Comment: i did add it to the question

Answer (score 0):

Had similar error when was running my app in iOS 8.1 simulator. Worked without errors in other iOS versions. Just plug in something in microphone slot on your Mac, restart app and error should disappear.